# Huge heap with very few allocations of Windows dump file

Tags: debugging, memory-leaks, heap-memory, windbg, dump

We have an application that has been running for more than 5 months and it is now using 3.5GB memory. We also noticed that the memory usage is slowly increasing day by day. So we suspect that there might be a memory leak somewhere and we used the DebugDiag tool to analyze the dump file we generated. However, we have a hard time to understand the analysis result.

### Update:

### It looks like the problem is coming from DebugDiag itself. I created another dump file myself and DebugDig showed there is only one heap allocation which is obviously wrong. So the new question is: Did I miss something when I open the .DMP file with DebugDig?

---

### Main question:

### The heap size is 3.35GB but the top 10 allocations sum up to less than 20 MB. So where is the rest of the memory used?

---

Below is the summary of heap analysis:

```
Heap Summary
Number of heaps   14 Heaps 
Total reserved memory   3.36 GBytes 
Total committed memory   3.33 GBytes
------------------------------------
Top 10 heaps by reserved memory

0x00240000                    3.35GBytes
0x00600000                    2.4MBytes
0x01fe0000                    2.4MBytes
......
------------------------------------
Top 10 heaps by committed memory
0x00240000                    3.35GBytes
0x00740000                    1.45MBytes
0x00600000                    1.44MBytes
......
```

The first heap is the default process heap and its size is consistent with our observation of the memory usage of the application. Below is the detailed information of the first heap:

```
Heap Details

Heap 1 - 0x00240000

Heap Name   Default process heap 
Heap Description   This heap is created by default and shared by all modules 
                   in the process 
Reserved memory   3.35 GBytes 
Committed memory   3.32 GBytes(99.13% of reserved) 
Uncommitted memory   29.89 MBytes(0.87% of reserved) 
Number of heap segments   217 segments 
Number of uncommitted ranges   227 range(s) 
Size of largest uncommitted range   11.19 MBytes 
Calculated heap fragmentation Unavailable
```

So obviously this heap has allocated 217 segments that sum up to 3.35GB. However, what confused me is the heap allocations that are shown below:

```
Top 10 allocations by size

Allocation Size - 1045632        5.98 MBytes
Allocation Size - 1048560        3 MBytes
Allocation Size - 1024000        1000 KBytes
Allocation Size - 1013248        989.5 KBytes
Allocation Size - 1005440        981.88 KBytes
Allocation Size - 1001216        977.75 KBytes
Allocation Size - 962528         939.97 KBytes
Allocation Size - 961272         938.74 KBytes
Allocation Size - 938088         916.1 KBytes
Allocation Size - 924672         903 KBytes
-------------------------------------

Top 10 allocations by count

Allocation Size - 1045632        6 allocations(s)
Allocation Size - 1048560        3 allocations(s)
Allocation Size - 17152          3 allocations(s)
Allocation Size - 261120         2 allocations(s)
Allocation Size - 48896          1 allocations(s)
Allocation Size - 86784          1 allocations(s)
Allocation Size - 96512          1 allocations(s)
Allocation Size - 98952          1 allocations(s)
Allocation Size - 117248         1 allocations(s)
Allocation Size - 132160         1 allocations(s)
```

So the top 10 allocations sum up to less than 20 MB of memory but the total heap size is 3.3 GB. I would like to where possibly the rest of the memory could go?

Comment: how did you fixed it. I am facing same issue and need your help.